# css3 submenu's submenu move to bottom of parent

Tags: html, css

i'm using sample of css3 menu, my problem is submenu's submenu and after move that to bottom of parent can't move mouse on that easily.

CSS3:

```
body {
    font: 0.8em/1.5em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(235, 235, 235);
    width: 900px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
}
a {
    color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
}
#nav {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 7px 6px 0px;
    background: url('gradient.png') repeat-x scroll 0px -110px rgb(125, 125, 125);
    line-height: 100%;
    border-radius: 2em 2em 2em 2em;
}
#nav li {
    margin: 0px 5px;
    padding: 0px 0px 8px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none outside none;
}
#nav a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(231, 229, 229);
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#nav a:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(0, 0, 0);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#nav .current a, #nav li:hover > a {
    background: url('gradient.png') repeat-x scroll 0px -40px rgb(102, 102, 102);
    color: rgb(68, 68, 68);
    border-top: 1px solid rgb(248, 248, 248);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#nav ul li:hover a, #nav li:hover li a {
    background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
    border: medium none;
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
}
#nav ul a:hover {
    background: url('gradient.png') repeat-x scroll 0px -100px rgb(0, 120, 255) ! important;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255) ! important;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#nav li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul {
    display: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 185px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 0px;
    background: url('gradient.png') repeat-x scroll 0px 0px rgb(221, 221, 221);
    border: 1px solid rgb(180, 180, 180);
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#nav ul li {
    float: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
#nav ul a {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#nav ul ul {
    left: 181px;
    top: 23px;
}
#nav ul li:first-child > a {
}
#nav ul li:last-child > a {
}
#nav:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0px;
}
#nav {
    display: inline-block;
}
html[xmlns] #nav {
    display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/">My Projects</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/">N.Design Studio</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/wp-themes">WordPress Themes</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/wallpapers">Wallpapers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.ndesign-studio.com/tutorials">Illustrator Tutorials</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://www.webdesignerwall.com/">Web Designer Wall</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://jobs.webdesignerwall.com/">Design Job Wall</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="http://icondock.com/">IconDock</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://bestwebgallery.com/">Best Web Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

this below code is submited on jsfiddle.demo, how to parent can be chide such az submenu's submenu
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CZLuq/)

Comment: Instead of give us the full code, you might want to have a really small part that you can't understand, and then ask for help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the submenus are displayed on hover. As you have set the grand child menu to display 23px from the top, if you move the mouse to the right, it is no longer hovering the child, and thus the menu disappears.

To fix it, you need to make the grand child menu to vertically line up with the child menu, so that it doesn't lose hover before the grand child gains hover. You can do this by setting the top value to 0:

```
#nav ul ul {
    left: 181px;
    top: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CZLuq/1/